# Using a for loop to copy one array to another

Tags: java

I've been working with arrays and I'm trying to find a way to copy one array to another solely with a for loop (I've seen things like arrayCopy and clone in other threads, but for this exercise I need to just copy from one array to another using a for loop).

Right now my code executes, but just spits this out: "[D@133c5982". The code I'm using is:

```
public class sorted 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int [] unSortedArray = {8,12,6,5,19};
        System.out.println(copyArray(unSortedArray));
        //System.out.println(sortedArray(unSortedArray));
    }

    public static int[] copyArray(int[] array)
    {
        int [] copyArray;
        copyArray = new int[array.length];
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        copyArray[i] = array[i];
    }
    return copyArray;
}
```

Comment: You can't print an array like this. Loop through it printing element by element or convert to string.

Comment: That's the default `toString()` implementation for arrays.  You should use `Arrays.toString(array)`.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you are **not** copying whole array, as you starting your index with 1

as in your code

```
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
{
        copyArray[i] = array[i];
}
```

start the index with 0

and second you can make use of `Arrays.deepToString(array)` or `Arrays.toString(array)` to print array in readable format

Comment: Thanks for showing me the method `deepToString`, I didnt know it existed!

Comment: no problem! if this answer solved your question then please accept it by clicking tick make to left answer

Answer (score 1):

Your code is OK, it does copy the array. When you do `System.out.println` it prints out the default implementation of the array's `toString()` method). To see that it is indeed copied, you can do

```
for (int i = 0; i<unsortedArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(unsortedArray[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i<copiedArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(copiedArray[i]);
}
```

EDIT: see the comments for what you code actually prints out

Comment: Actually, it prints out the array object's `toString` which is the type signature plus hashcode for the object, which may or may not be an address.

Answer (score 0):

`copyArray` returns an array and that's what you are printing. What you see is the Java Virtual Machine way of representing objects as strings. @12345 is the object's ID.

There is nothing wrong with the code provided, except a } at the end (possibly omitted while copying).

Answer (score 0):

When printing you are using the arrays default `toString` which doesn't print the content of the Strings.

Since Java 1.5 you can use `Arrays.toString(array)` to get a nice String representation of the array.

[See the API here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29).

Use this with `System.out.println` to get a nice printout.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is correct. But if you print an array using `System.out.println(copyArray(unSortedArray));` it only prints out the location of the array. Instead, try printing each element of the array in a for loop.

```
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
{
   system.out.println(array[i]);
}
//Arrays.toString(<arrayname>) can also be used in place of the for loop.
```

Also, array index starts at 0. So, your method should be as follows.

```
public static int[] copyArray(int[] array)
{
    int [] copyArray;
    copyArray = new int[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    copyArray[i] = array[i];
}
return copyArray;
```

Comment: @Makoto Oh. I always thought it was the hash value.Thanks for the info.

Comment: Nah, I was off.  I went back, printed out the hex value of the hash code, and they match.

Comment: @Makoto Aah. So it is both hash code hex value and the memory location.Or just the hash value?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 package naveed.workingfiles;

 import java.util.Arrays;

 public class Array 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int [] unSortedArray = {8,12,6,5,19};
    int [] unSortedCopyArray =new  int [unSortedArray.length];

    //System.out.println(sortedArray(unSortedArray));
    for(int i=0;i<unSortedArray.length;i++)
    {
        unSortedCopyArray[i]=unSortedArray[i];
    }           
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(unSortedArray));//exist array
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(unSortedCopyArray));//copied array


}

}
```

Comment: Nope - you can print the array in one go without having to use a loop.